# How to make simple text swap when button pressed on android studio

Tags: java, android

I need to display a random message when a button is clicked.

I am trying to use  `<i> txt.setText(mystring);<i>` to achieve it.

But it says I have to use **android resources**. What is the simplest and efficient way to achieve it using android resources?

Comment: You need something like change your text view string with any other random string on button click?

Comment: more details and better grammar, code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope to help:

```
<string-array name="myArray"> 
    <item>string 1</item> 
    <item>string 2</item> 
    <item>string 3</item> 
    <item>string 4</item> 
    <item>string 5</item>
</string-array>
```

You can then create an array to hold the strings and select a random string from the array to use:

```
private String[] myString; 

myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
```

Example code:

```
package com.test.test200;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txt.setText(q);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "myText";
textView.setText(text);
```

Is completely valid. What it's saying is that static strings like text (that don't ever change), should be stored in resources/values/strings. That's so it's easier for you to change in the future, or if you want to translate your application.

Have a look at this [android post](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)